# merging one or more tables

Tags: excel, merge

i'm having 6 tables in microsoft excel and i'm trying to merge them all in order to compare the records. i've tried all kinds of joins using power queries but getting null values for unmatched records. is there any way that I don't get the null values for the unmatched records rather get all the merged data at once?

Comment: If the tables have the same structure, you are probably using power query incorrectly. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then **edit your question** to provide enough information, as well as the code you have tried, so others can help you.  Please post your data as **text** which can be copy/pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Do all tables have the same structure?
If the case that the sheets have the same structure, it will be enough to always copy and paste with the option "Same as the source format (M)" In case they are different I hope you expand the information a little more so that I know how to proceed to help you. Receive an affectionate Greeting.

Comment: thank you for answering sir! yes the tables have same structure but are on different sheets in the workbook! do you mean pasting as Keep Source Formatting (K)? coz I can't find (M)! also, as there are some common records as well, in all the tables, that's why I want to merge them and compare on single sheet, is there any way?

Comment: In fact, I mean "Keep source formatting", he used the Spanish version and that is why perhaps I activate the option with (m).  Now, I hope it is not too late the answer, there is nothing that automates that task, perhaps now it is convenient to use a small macro that is responsible for joining all the sheets into one. I want to think you can handle that.